Send a React Native event from iOS AppDelegate Subscribers
I'm developing an Expo application using the Modules API and iOS AppDelegate Subscribers.
I want to send a React Native event to JavaScript whenever the didReceiveRemoteNotification lifecycle method is triggered in the AppDelegate Subscriber.
So far, I’ve tried accessing the modules-core AppContext, which contains a reference to the EXEventEmitterService. This service provides the sendEventWithName method, which seems like the right tool for the job, but I haven’t been able to figure out how to get a reference to it.
Has anyone worked with a similar setup or knows how to handle this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
